# Does the induced representation always contain a non-trivial representation

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of a finite group $G$ - **not normal**.

Does $Ind_H^G 1$ contain a non-trivial representation?

The Frobenius character formula was my original approach, but I can't rule out that the trace of $Ind_H^G 1$:
$$g \mapsto  \# \{ x \in H\backslash G: x^{-1}gx \in H \}$$
is not the constant function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are non-constant functions on $H\backslash G$, so the right-translation action of $G$ on this space is not a sum of trivial repns of $G$.

Comment: Ah okay. If there would be only a multiple of the trivial representation all vectors=matrix coefficients would be constant.